# Use Pager with a webservice

Tags: paging

I use a webservice to get data instead of using mysql and I try to show results with a pagination:

```
function partenaire_search_partners(){
  $results = partenaire_ws_get_partners();
  foreach($results->Partenaire as $partenaire) {
    $rows[] = array($partenaire->raisonSociale);
  }

  $headers = array(
      array(
          'data' => t('Raison Sociale')
      )
  );
  $output = theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $rows)) . theme('pager');


  return $output;
}
```

I can restrieve my data, but either with 10 or 200 results I never see the pagination. Do you have some clues to help me resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141037/how-to-give-pagination-for-rest-service-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Drupal 7 then copy paste this function after your partenaire_search_partners()

```
function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

// Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
$pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);

// We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
$pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
$pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
$pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element],   ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
```

and add this line to below of your foreach loop

```
  $paging =  pager_array_splice($rows, 10);
```

then use copy this line

```
   $output = theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $paging)) . theme('pager');
```

instead of this

```
     $output = theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $rows)) . theme('pager');
```

Comment: it gives 10 records in each page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


/*
* Implements hook_mennu()
*/
function test_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title'             => t('Test'),
    'page callback'     => 'test_search_page',
    'access callback'   => True,
  );

  return $items;
}


function test_search_page(){
    $form = drupal_get_form('test_search_form');

    return $form;
}


function test_search_form($form, &$form_state){
  $header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));
  $rows = Null;
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'textfield',
    '#title'            => t('Name'),
    '#required'         => True,
    '#default_value'    => isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : Null
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'           => 'submit',
    '#value'          => t('submit'),
  );



  if (isset($_GET['name'])){
    $rows = get_data();
  }
  $form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('Aucun résultat.')
  );
  $form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));

  /*
  if (isset($form_state['table'])) {
    $form['table']  = $form_state['table'];
  }
  $form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));
  */
  return $form;
}

function test_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    // $path
    'test',
    // $options
    array('query' => array('name' => $form_state['values']['name'])),
    // $http_response_code
    302,
  );
}

//$header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));

function get_data(){
    $data =  array(
        0   => array(
            'id' => '0',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        1   => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        2   => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        3   => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        4   => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        5   => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        6   => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        7   => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        8   => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        9   => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        10   => array(
            'id' => '10',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        11   => array(
            'id' => '11',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        )
    );
    $paging = pager_array_splice($data, 2);

    return $paging;
}
/*
    $header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));

    $form_state['table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $paging,
      '#empty' => t('Aucun r?sultat.')
    );

    $form_state['rebuild'] = True;*/


function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

  // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
  $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);

  // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
  $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
  $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
  $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
  return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
```